# facebook open graph parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a code in **index.php** file like below:

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/vanlelu:cook?food=http://fabubu.com/MKK/exam/**cookie1.php**', 'post',);

And a file **cookie1.php**.

They are all working well (can post activity to wall of tester account).

But, i wondering is there any way to send parameters to cookie1.php.

I have tryed this but its not working:

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/vanlelu:cook?food=http://fabubu.com/MKK/exam/cookie1.php?para=123456', 'post',);

### Please help....

Updated:
have find one solution like below:

$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/vanlelu:cook', 'post',array('food' => 'http://fabubu.com/MKK/exam/cookie1.php?id=1234678'));

Now, the file 'cookie1.php' can $_GET['id'] by value '1234678'.

But when i change the value '1234678', this api command not work well, even i change parameter.

Not working: $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/vanlelu:cook', 'post',array('food' => 'http://fabubu.com/MKK/exam/cookie1.php?id=1234678888888888888'));

Not working: $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/vanlelu:cook', 'post',array('food' => 'http://fabubu.com/MKK/exam/cookie1.php?iddddddddddd=1234678'));

It seem facebook open graph remember exactly my parameter and its value. When i change one of them, its got error.

Could you make a page and try the code I gave?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works

```
 $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/vanlelu:cook?food=http://fabubu.com/MKK/exam/cookie1.php', 'post',array('para'=>123456));
```

Comment: well I've looked into this more and facebook only supports $_GET when it comes to the object_url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/#publish

Comment: I cant find a way to get out this problem. Please help!

Comment: could you use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to rewrite a url? So your action could be http://example.com/cookie/1/ and in your .htaccess file rewrite that to http://example.com/cookie.php?id=1  I think that should probably work, though it would be $_GET not $_POST

Comment: Dear TommyBS, thank for your helping. the 'id' could increase up to millions, its means i have to write millions 'example.com/cookie.php?id=...' in .htaccess file. Right?

Comment: no you wouldn't have to add each one. You can use regular expressions. I'm not an expert on .htaccess but something similar to this might work

RewriteRule ^cookie/([0-9]+)/?$  /cookie.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

Comment: I will try, and i will send you a result. Thank for helping me.